# Getting c++ runtime error when using a vector of SDL_Rect in SDL_blitsurface

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks, block

l    SDL_BlitSurface(tileSheets.at(sheet), &clip[tile], screen, &tileBox);

Works just fine and i initiliaze the clips like this:

```
clip[ 0 ].x = x;
clip[ 0 ].y = y;
clip[ 0 ].w = 48;
clip[ 0 ].h = 48;
x += 48;
clip[ 1 ].x = x;
clip[ 1 ].y = y;
clip[ 1 ].w = 48;
clip[ 1 ].h = 48;
```

This however doesnt work at all

```
SDL_BlitSurface(tileSheets.at(sheet), &clip.at(tile), screen, &tileBox);
```

I initilize them like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        SDL_Rect clipBox = {x,y,48,48};
        clip.push_back(clipBox);
    }
```

This is the error i get: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/83468944.png/

Any clues?

Comment: It seems like you are overindexing the array (`at()` throws an excaption when the index is out of bounds, `[]` on the same index is undefined behavior) -- make sure your `tile` is within 0 and `number-1` (bounds included)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the type of variable clip, but it might be that you are pushing variables in the stack to the vector, so they turn invalid once you exit scope of the for loop.

Comment: when you call `push_back()` on a collection, it creates a copy of the passed-object, so scope is not an issue here -- also if it was, `[]` would fail as well as `at()`

Comment: That would depend on the type of clip. If it is a vector storing references, then copies will not be created.

Comment: This is how i create them both(not both at the same time tho):

vector<SDL_Rect> clip;
SDL_Rect clip[2];

Comment: true, but then `[]` should fail as well

Comment: Who knows really?  It could be that the SDL libs were built using different vector options and the two are incompatible.  We don't have enough information here.  We can't see how this thing is being created, we don't know the value of `sheet` or `tile`, etc.  It's just a big guessing game at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
 /* 1) */  SDL_Rect clipBox(x,y,48,48);
 /* 2) */  clip.push_back(SDL_Rect(x,y,48,48));
```